# Two particles state of a 1D massive scalar field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, condensed-matter

Perfectly localized states are not normalized so do not belong to the Fock space (they belong to the rigged version). Suppose we approximate localized states with gaussians, what is the mathematical expression for two "approximately" localized particles at points $x_1$ and $x_2$ that takes into account correlations due to vacuum entanglement? how do you build it from the original creation/annihilation operators eigenstates?

The field is supposed to be a 1D massive scalar one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general two-particle state will look like

$\displaystyle \int dp_1 dp_2 \psi(p_1,p_2) a^\dagger_{p_1} a^\dagger_{p_2}| 0\rangle
$

Here $\psi(p_1,p_2)$ is the momentum-space wavefunction. Since the creation operators commute, only the symmetric part matters, so we may as well take  $\psi(p_1,p_2)=\psi(p_2,p_1)$ (there would be a minus sign if they were fermions). If you would like the state to be normalizable, it should be square integrable.

The position-space wavefunction  $\psi(x_1,x_2)$, is the Fourier transform.

You can then choose this to be supported when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are close to the positions at which you would like to localize the particles (or vice-versa, because of the symmetry: the particles are indistinguishable), for example by Gaussians. The phase can then carry information on the momenta of the particles (as is hopefully familiar from 1-particle Gaussians), as well as on how the two are entangled.

This really doesn't depend much on the details of the sort of particle you're talking about, except the wavefunction will be symmetric or antisymmetric depending on whether you have bosons and fermions, and particles other than scalars will carry spin degrees of freedom so the wavefunction becomes a matrix.